# JBoss 7 not logging Maven property

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have a Maven based WAR module.
In the main pom I've defined a custom property as follows:

```
<properties>
    <prop>TEST</prop>
</properties>
```

I'm running a local instance of JBoss 7.3 with the following command:

`./bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone_TEST.xml -Dprop=CLI_TEST`

And in the standalone_TEST.xml a logging pattern is thus defined:

`<pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p (%X{prop}) [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>`

Unfortunately `prop` doesn't seem to be populated as the logs always look similar to this:

`19:09:57,872 INFO  () [com.test.lib.TestController] (default task-1) Logging some details`

I tried setting the custom property via code through MDC.put() and it worked fine, so it looks like the logging framework is not picking up neither the Maven property nor the command line property.

Any idea what could be the issue?

--- Editing

The logging system used is the default JBoss **LogManager**, no other logging subsystems were defined.

I'm wondering now whether what I'm trying to do is even possible. Even ignoring for the time being the use case with the Maven property, I would have guessed that passing the system property via command line should have worked, but still nothing gets logged.

Comment: What logging framework are you using? What has Maven to do with Java properties or logging?

Comment: As per my additional editing to the post: I'm using the default JBoss LogManager.I was guessing that defining a global param via Maven was enough to be caught by the logging framework, similarly to passing a sys param directly via command line

Comment: Maven properties don't exist at runtime.

Comment: Yes, you are right, so I'm now trying to replace the default LogManager with logback so that I can use the Maven property to replace a placeholder in the logback.xml at build time and that would be available f6or the runtime. The issue is now with the logback dependency that my module is not picking up correctly, but I see several such cases on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDC is not set through system properties. To include a system property in your log pattern you need to use `%#{TEST}`.

Comment: Unfortunately this format doesn't seem to be interpreted as it is logged directly as string, please see my additional details to the original post, thanks.

Comment: Using `#{TEST}` should work. That should get the system property named `TEST`. Using `%X{TEST}` does a `MDC.get("TEST")` which is not a system property.

Comment: I don't know... with no other changes than passing a property via command line through -D and adding something like myprop=#{TEST} in the standalone.xml under <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0"><formatter...> the logs are printing directly the string "myprop=#{TEST}"

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I'll fix the answer. It should be `%#{TEST}`. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Logging system properties with the syntax you provided works fine, thanks.